# google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag Error in Protocol Buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsondecoder, protocol-buffers

I trying decrypt my data using google protocol buffer in python

**sample.proto file:-**

```
syntax = "proto3";

message SimpleMessage {
string deviceID = 1;
string timeStamp = 2;
string data = 3;
 }
```

After that, I have generated python files using the proto command:-
`protoc --proto_path=./ --python_out=./ simple.proto`

**My Python code below:-**

```
import json
import simple_pb2
import base64


encryptedData = 'iOjEuMCwic2VxIjoxODEsInRtcyI6IjIwMjEtMDEtMjJUMTQ6MDY6MzJaIiwiZGlkIjoiUlFI'

t2 = bytes(encryptedData, encoding='utf8')
print(encryptedData)
data = base64.b64decode(encryptedData)

test = simple_pb2.SimpleMessage()
v1 =  test.ParseFromString(data)
```

While executing above code getting error:- **google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag Error**

What i am doing wrong. can anyone help?

Comment: How did you get the encrypted data?

Comment: @gwenzek:- It encrypted from protocol buffer. The actual data is in json format

Answer (score 2):

Your data is not "encrypted", it's just base64-encoded. If you use your example code and inspect your `data` variable, then you get:

```
import base64

data = base64.b64decode(b'eyJ2ZXIiOjEuMCwic2VxIjoxODEsInRtcyI6IjIwMjEtMDEtMjJUMTQ6MDY6MzJaIiwiZGlkIjoiUlFIVlRKRjAwMDExNzY2IiwiZG9wIjoxLjEwMDAwMDAyMzg0MTg1NzksImVyciI6MCwiZXZ0IjoiVE5UIiwiaWdzIjpmYWxzZSwibGF0IjoyMi45OTI0OTc5OSwibG5nIjo3Mi41Mzg3NDgyOTk5OTk5OTUsInNwZCI6MC4wfQo=')
print(data)

> b'{"ver":1.0,"seq":181,"tms":"2021-01-22T14:06:32Z","did":"RQHVTJF00011766","dop":1.1000000238418579,"err":0,"evt":"TNT","igs":false,"lat":22.99249799,"lng":72.538748299999995,"spd":0.0}\n'
```

Which is evidently a piece of of JSON data, *not* a binary-serialized protocol buffer - which is what `ParseFromString` expects. Also, looking at the names and types of the fields, it looks like this payload just doesn't match the proto definition you've shown.

There are certainly ways to parse a JSON into a proto, and even to [control the field names](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/8080bebf1f2ff87ef96a24135afe7f82d2eb3d2a/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto#L213) in that transformation, but not even the number of fields match directly. So you first need to define what you *want*: what proto message would you expect this JSON object to represent?